# Best way to get licenses for mvn jars

Tags: maven

My company needs a license file for every single transitive dependency in a mvn dependency.   Is there a good CLI command that will grab just that?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean the license entries in the pom files? Or do you refer to different "license files"?

Comment: The license entries in the pom files would be a good start.  Legal needs the license for each jar file to verify that it complies with their policies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work with the `license:download-licenses` goal of the License Maven Plugin:

http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/

It is able to gather the licenses in one directory (and other formatting as detailed in the documentation).

As `includeTransitiveDependencies` has default value `true`, it should grab all the indirect licenses as well.